# How can I view the completed stages in the pipeline with more stages or repeated stages efficiently

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a pipeline job which run some sequence of action (Eg; Build >> Run >> Report). I have put this sequence in a for loop as I can get a parameter which has list of value for which I should repeat the same sequence. Please find the sample code I have written.

```
param_val = params.param_1
param_list = param_val.split()
for (int i = 0; i < size(param_list); ++i){
    item_value = param_list[i].trim()
    builds[i] ={
        stage('Build') {
            build 'Build', parameters: [string(name: 'item', value: item_value)]
        }
        stage('Run') {
           build 'Run', parameters: [string(name: 'item', value: item_value)]
        }
        stage('Reporting') {
           build 'Reporting', parameters: [string(name: 'item', value: item_value)]
        }
    }parallel builds
}
```

I can get even more than 100 values for the iteration. So it is difficult to track it in the pipeline stage view. it just grows to right side. 
Do we have any other plugin which can be used for the status view ? Some tree like view would be good.

Comment: Have you tried blue ocean?

Comment: @hakamairi , Thank you for the answer and blue ocean UI looks so good... Can I edit the name of eacn parallel item? It shows just 0, 1. If I can edit , it would be more helpful.

Comment: Just try wrapping this with a stage instead of closure ;)

Comment: you might need to used `stages` like `stage('my outer'){ stages { //your_stages } }`